# Why do we use \n rather than return key directly in java string?

Tags: java, string, compilation

We can use \n to stand for linefeed in string. But why we can't use return key directly?

```
String str1 = "\n";
//error
String str2 = "
";
```

I guess the reason for this limitation is that if I forget the right double quotation marks, compiler will not detect this error until end of file.

Comment: The `\n` does make the code easier to read, even if `str2` in the example works. Reading the code, I can't tell how many spaces or tabs might be between the quote marks.

Comment: The `str2` example does give a compiler error on my machine. It thinks I have an unclosed `String` literal.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you use `\n` instead of the return key directly as the return key is considered a "non-graphic" character in the world of Java (as well as an overwhelming majority of other programming languages). Characters like return, tabs, etc. can cause compiler and/or style issues when used in strings directly for most programing languages (like Java).

`\n` is an escape sequence that is a fill-in for these non-graphic characters. The reason these exist is it can reduce the readability of code to use non-graphic characters in Java strings.

You can read more about escape sequences for characters in Java here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6